# how to search between two mysql unix timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix, timestamp

Hi mysql unix timestamp are stored in date column of my table now i am searching from date picker with two fields i.e. `from_date` and `to_date` but I did not found any records tried a lot of ways but not succeeded my date picker date is like this `08/22/2017` while unix timestamps stored in table are like

```
1503380449
1503380428
1503380326
```

how can i fire mysql query to get records between two dates I tried mysql UNIX timestamp functions but not working.

I tried this :-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE
my_date BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('2017/08/22', '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x')
AND
STR_TO_DATE('2017/08/22', '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x')
```

I tried this:-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE
my_date BETWEEN 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2017/08/22', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')
AND
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2017/08/22', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')
```

I also tried this:-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE
my_date BETWEEN 
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Aug 22 2017 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')))
AND
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Aug 22 2017 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')))
```

thanks

Comment: you have to parse the value of datepicker to change it in timestamp to compare, you should have a look on http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @MacBooc I want all record of particular date using that timestamp stored in mysql table

Comment: did you try my anwser ?

Comment: @MacBooc I am using zend framework i wrote this code  $select->where("my_date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$from_date."00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$to_date."00:00:00')"); but its not working while if i fire its query then its working but i am not getting same date result means if from date and to date are same then i am not getting records

Comment: Then i'll edit my code because the problem here is that i put two date at the begining of the day, tell me if it's ok to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do in mysql you should use the  UNIX_TIMESTAMP function

PHP:

```
$from_date = "08/22/2017";
$from_date = substr($from_date, 6, 4) . "-" . substr($from_date, 0, 2) . "-" . substr($from_date, 3, 2);
$to_date = "08/30/2017";
$to_date = substr($to_date, 6, 4) . "-" . substr($to_date, 0, 2) . "-" . substr($to_date, 3, 2);
```

MYSQL :

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE
my_date BETWEEN 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$from_date." 00:00:00')
AND
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$to_date." 23:59:59')" // changed here to have the end of the day in case that the query is on the same day
```

or
PHP :

```
$from_date = strtotime("08/22/2017");
$to_date = strtotime("08/30/2017");
```

MYSQL :

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE
my_date BETWEEN 
".$from_date."
AND
".$to_date
```

Comment: but i wanna suggest you that rather then doing substr for conversion we can simply use this way date('Y-m-d',strtotime("08/22/2017")); what you say ?

Comment: Yeah it's also a good idea, BUT if you want to use this, you can directly use strtotime("08/22/2017") to have the timestamp, i thought that you wanted to do in SQL i'll edit to show you